# GMail Sync off but still syncs

Tags: gmail

I just started using GMail on my Galaxy J3, just like the built-in email app if I turn off sync in GMail it still sync's.  If I turn off sync in built-in app then I can't send/receive - that's why I tried GMail - at least in GMail w/sync off I can send/receive.

Comment: So what exactly is the issue, that the built-in mail app won't send or receive when sync is turned off on it?  I don't see a real question here.

Comment: There are two questions - neither GMail or built-in app work properly.  I don't particularly care which I use I just want email that functions w/o syncing.